# Help with identifying Lego set (partial red and yellow bike)

Tags: set-identification

I purchased a mixed bag of parts from a local seller and the pictured item was in the bag.  I do not recognize it and would like some help with kit number, description, etc.

[image: mystery Lego bike]

Answer (score 6):

This is from set # [9441: Kai's Blade Cycle](https://brickset.com/sets/9441-1/Kai-s-Blade-Cycle)
[image: 9441: Kai's Blade Cycle]

Keypart;
[85970 - Slope, Curved 10 x 1, in Red](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=85970&colorID=5&in=A)

Comment: With some serious modifications and many missing pieces.